# Balance between use of Ajax on $.ready() and loading data already

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, dynamic, pageload

I have a page which has several independent sections. Data is to be populated in each section by different queries to the database.

In order to lower the page load time, I have ajaxified the loading of each section (following the Amazon.com philosophy).
In order to load each section of the page, I make an ajax call on `$.ready()` method in my page which in turn fetches data from the database.

In all 6 requests are made to the (same) server which completely generate the sections.
Now, I'm not sure if I am overburdening the server by making 6 requests each time the page is requested. Any suggestions?

(I use Struts/Hibernate/Jsp/jQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always queue your ajax calls so they happen 1 at a time.  There are jquery plugins to help with this:

http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/

To me however, 6 calls does not seem too bad, as long as they dont generate a lot of server activity (hard db queries, file handling, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can start all your queries as soon as the page is requested, and save the results up for the ajax calls. This needs asynchronous execution on the server, and you need to make sure that the ajax response program can wait for the sql completion too.

If you query the same data in several of your 6 queries, this might be worth it. If tables are different for each, this might be really counterproductive (depending on your database engine, and cluster architecture).

However, if database stress and response time is a concern, caching techniques and other optimisations usually work better (memcache by example). But again this depends strongly on your database engine.